# Exclude results from an SQL Query - Big by Area or Population, but not Both (Exclusive OR)

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am stuck on Q.8 on this [tutorial from SqlZoo](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial) which is a followup to Q.7:

> **Question #7**
>
> Two ways to be big: A country is big if it has an area of more than 3 million sq km or it has a population of more than 250 million.
>
> Show the countries that are big by area or big by population. Show name, population and area.

> **Question #8**
>
> USA and China are big in population and big by area. Exclude these countries.
>
> Show the countries that are *big by area **or** big by population but **not both***. Show name, population and area.

The code I have had some success with is:

```
SELECT name, population, area
FROM world 
WHERE area > 3000000 
OR population > 250000000
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name, population, area 
    FROM world 
    WHERE name='USA' 
    OR 'China'
)
```

but 'China' and 'USA' still appear in my results! Can someone show me how to write a WHERE clause to remove them?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem here. Links have a habit of breaking.

Answer (score 11):

*(Note this is OP's Question 8 - Question 7 would just be `OR`)*

The logical operation requiring either condition A, or condition B, but not both simultaneously, is *Exclusive Or*, and is abbreviated to [**XOR**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

This is supported by Ansi Sql, so the answer can be obtained by using `XOR` in the comparison criteria, like so:

```
  SELECT name, population, area
  FROM world
  WHERE (population > 250000000) XOR (area > 3000000);
```

**Re : More Intuitive Alternative**

You can expand `XOR` to:

```
  WHERE ((population > 250000000) OR (area > 3000000)) 
       AND NOT ((population > 250000000) AND (area > 3000000))
```

But in the general sense, rather than repeating the logic determining whether a country is `big` (by area or population), it might be easier to understand by using a derived table, which reasons over the population and area, and then the derived columns can be reused in the filter logic in the outer query:

```
SELECT name, population, area
FROM
(SELECT
     name, population, area,
     CASE WHEN population > 250000000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsBigPop,
     CASE WHEN area > 3000000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsBigArea
   FROM world
) DerivedWorld
WHERE (IsBigPop = 1 OR IsBigArea = 1) AND NOT (IsBigPop = 1 AND IsBigArea = 1);
```

(and of course you could abbreviate the `WHERE` clause to `XOR` as well)

Comment: Unfortunately, that is far too advanced for me to begin to understand, and it also returns an incorrect answer 'Wrong answer. Some of the data is incorrect'.

Comment: My bad - I was returning the correct rows, but the wrong columns, hence the 'wrong answer'. I've used a derived table. I'll explain with an update.

Comment: That works but it will take me some time to figure out how to write like that. Seeing as it's a beginner level tutorial I would have thought there was a very simple answer that had been previously covered as neither of what you suggested (XOR included) were explained. Thank you.

Comment: Then I guess start with my second example (OR .. AND NOT ... AND). The XOR approach probably will only appeal to those familar with truth tables (and electronics). But try and grasp the concept behind CASE ... WHEN projections and derived tables - they allow you to break down complex problems into little steps, one at a time.

Comment: The OP's question is from the sqlzoo.net tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Can use

```
select name, population, area
from world 
where ( area>3000000 or population>250000000 )
and name not in ( 'USA', 'China' )
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, population, area FROM world WHERE (area>3000000 OR population>250000000) AND name NOT IN('USA','China')
```

Answer (score 1):

The complete answer is really already in the question, you just need to translate it to boolean terms that the query engine can understand.

Your query starts our correct, you're just lacking the last bit, i.e. one OR the other should apply BUT NOT BOTH.

```
SELECT name, population, area
FROM world 
WHERE 
-- The first clause select all that match either or both criteria
(
    area > 3000000 
    OR population > 250000000
) 
-- The second clause filters those that match both criteria
AND NOT (
    area > 3000000 
    AND population > 250000000
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am doing the same tutorial and I was having the same issue. They did not phrase the question correctly and some criteria is missing. Here is my answer:

```
select name, population, area
from world 
where ( area>3000000 or population>250000000 )
and name not in ( 'United States', 'China', 'India')
;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Consider the following arguments-**

(Area>3000000 AND Population<250000000): Countries only BIG by Area

(Area<3000000 AND Population<250000000): Countries only BIG by Population

**Therefore, Final code will be like -**

```
select name, population, area from world 
where (area > 3000000 and population < 250000000) OR 
      (area < 3000000 and population > 250000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select name, population, area
from world where ( area>3000000 or population>250000000 ) and name not in ( 'USA', 'China' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, population, area
FROM world 
WHERE (area > 3000000 OR population > 250000000)
AND name NOT IN ('United states', 'China') 
AND NOT (area > 3000000 AND population > 250000000)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    name, 
    population, 
    area
from 
    world
where 
    (population >250000000 or area >3000000)
    AND NOT (
        area > 3000000 
        AND population > 250000000)
```

This answer works

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  name, population, area
FROM    world
WHERE   population > 250000000 XOR area > 3000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

> Select name, population, area from world
>
> Where *(area >3000000 Or population >250000000)*
>
> And Not *(area >3000000 And population >250000000)*

Answer (score 0):

I just did this same tutorial.  Here is the answer i got to work.  *notice the order of  "name, population, area"*.  it will not register as correct in a different order.

select name, population, area
from world
where ( area > 3000000 or population > 250000000 )
AND NOT ( area > 3000000 AND population > 250000000 )

Answer (score 0):

**Question 7**

```
SELECT name, population, area
FROM world
WHERE area > 3000000 OR population > 250000000;
```

**Question 8**

The code written below is about as concise a syntax you could get. It is possible to target the specific countries mentioned, as in `WHERE name NOT IN ('United States', 'China')`, but data changes over time.

```
SELECT name, population, area
FROM world 
WHERE (population > 250000000 OR area > 3000000) 
       AND NOT (population > 250000000 AND area > 3000000);
```

It is possible down the road that the population of a country increases past 250,000,000. For example, the website you reference now includes India with the United States and China.

Answer (score 0):

I check below query, this worked well :

```
SELECT name, population, area
  FROM world
  WHERE (population > 250000000) OR (area > 3000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Formulate the query as follows:

```
select name, population, area
from world
where (population >250000000 or area>3000000)
and name not in ('united states','china','india')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, population, area 
FROM world
WHERE (area > 3000000 XOR population > 250000000)
AND (name NOT IN ('India', 'United States', 'China'))
```

I got this one correct and fulfilled all the requirements it asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select name ,population, area 
      from world 
     where (area > 3000000 or population > 250000000)
       and name not in (select name from world where area > 3000000 and population > 250000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    name,
    population,
    area 
FROM 
    world
WHERE 
    name NOT IN ('United States', 'India', 'China')
    AND 
    population > 250000000 
    OR 
    area > 3000000
    AND NOT 
    (
        (population > 250000000) 
        AND 
        (area > 3000000)
    )
```

This is what I ran to exclude particular countries and limit my criteria for either population or area

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, population, area
FROM world 
WHERE (area > 3000000 
OR population > 250000000)
AND name not in ('united States','INDIA','China')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, population, area
from world 
where ( area > 3000000 or population > 250000000 )
and name not in ('USA');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code,

```
select name,population,area 
from world
where area> 3000000 OR population > 250000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT name, population, area
FROM world
WHERE ((population > 250000000) AND NOT(area > 3000000)) 
       OR((area > 3000000) AND NOT(population > 250000000))
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT name , population, area
FROM world 
WHERE (area > 3000000 or population > 250000000) 

except

SELECT name , population, area
FROM world 
WHERE (area > 3000000 and population > 250000000)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select name, population, area
from world 
where ( area>3000000 or population>250000000 )
and name not in ( 'United States', 'China', 'India')
```

Someone might have taken out India from SQLZOO.  I'm not an admin, but I edited it back into the question.  Otherwise,  most of these posts are correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name, population , area FROM world WHERE ((area > 3000000 && population < 250000000) OR ( area < 3000000 && population > 250000000)) AND (name NOT IN ('USA' , 'India' , 'China'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct answer for question#7 is

```
select name,population,area
from world
where (area>3000000 AND population<25000000) OR
      (area<3000000 AND population>25000000) OR
      (area>3000000 AND population>25000000)
```